# Long running multi threaded application runs 4x slower when deployed to tomcat than when run from command line

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

When I run this long running process from the command line it takes about 30 seconds to complete. When I deploy this same code to tomcat7 and call the same function from a simple Vaadin web application it takes almost 150 seconds. This is the time for a specific function to execute, not anything related to interface slowing it down.

Here's is a simple example that illustrates the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        multiCounter(800);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    System.out.println("Completed");
}


public static void multiCounter(int numberOfCounters) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
{   

    //estimate the number of available processors
    int maxNumberOfThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    //create thread pool and queue for future jobs
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxNumberOfThreads);

    ArrayList<Future<Integer>> futureJobs = new ArrayList<Future <Integer>>();

    for(int index=0; index<numberOfCounters; index++)       
    {
        Callable<Integer> callable = new dummyCalculator();
        Future<Integer> future = pool.submit(callable);
        futureJobs.add(future);
    }

    //placeholder for results
    ArrayList <Integer> results= new ArrayList <Integer>(0);

    //pull completed jobs from queue and extract results,
    //adding to results container
    for(Future<Integer> future : futureJobs) 
    {results.add(future.get());}

    for(Integer res : results)
    {System.out.println("Count:" + res);}

    //close thread pool
    pool.shutdown();
}

final static class dummyCalculator implements Callable<Integer>
{   
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {

        Integer counter = 0;

        for(int p1Index=0; p1Index<800; p1Index++)
        {   
            for(int p2Index=p1Index; p2Index<800; p2Index++)
            {
                for(int markerIndex=0; markerIndex<200; markerIndex++)
                {counter++;}
            }
        }

        return(counter);
    }
}
```

The server I'm running this on has 48 available cores. When I run this code from the command line I get 48 threads running ~98% each. When I run it through tomcat each thread tops out at around 82-86% according to top. If I decrease the number of threads in the code on tomcat, the % per thread increases. 12 threads will get me 92% per thread. 1 thread 99%...

Does tomcat do something to limit this tread pool in some way, or have some additional overhead with threads that I am not aware of? Or is there a better way to multi-thread in this case? Some overhead is obviously acceptable, but something doesn't seem right here for it to take that much longer through tomcat.

Comment: It seems unlikely/impossible that Tomcat would have any effect on the runtime of the specific lines that you posted.  Can you give a high level overview of LongRunningProcess?  It seems more likely to me that something they are doing is slowing down rather than something you posted.  Or do you have some reason for knowing it is the control logic you posted and not the task logic?

Comment: Thanks @Pace I've updated the question with more complete code that causes this problem on my tomcat server. Even with this trivial loop it seems to take significatnly longer when running through tomcat.

Comment: Is Tomcat busy trying to get any work done? Are you putting any load on Tomcat by, say, making HTTP requests?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Shouldn't be, this is the only task running and I'm the only one running anything on this server. I've restarted tomcat in between trials just to be sure something wasn't stuck somehow....

Comment: I ask because Tomcat starts up its own thread pools for various things (request-processing) and runs a background thread or two. If you have any load on Tomcat which requires some of those threads to do any work, then you are going to of course interrupt those threads that are busy counting up to 128M for some reason. Why are you running this in Tomcat? Do you *plan on* adding any request-load?

Comment: The simple counter function is just a sample that reproduces the same effect as I am seeing in my full application. Request load will be very minimal, as in a couple of users.

Comment: If you will be using a whole bunch of processors to do some CPU-intensive work, you ought to use a few less than the total number of processors you have, otherwise the request-processing threads for the application server might get starved. If you have 48 CPUs, I might consider using more like 40-45 of them for your CPU-intensive processes, and leaving the others for other work (including the OS, other services, etc.).

Comment: My guess is that the Tomcat thread waiting for the results is bigger that in command line program. This might cause context switching to be bigger operation than in stand alone. To test this theory try lowering the priority of thread waiting for results.

Other option is that tomcat process is started with different settings. Also there might be very big pool for handler threads (48 cpus and 32 GB ram hints so). Try to reduce the amount of pooled handler threads Tomcat uses.

Comment: Or most likely there is something in the calculation that causes the slow down. Maybe SecurityManager is being touched or something like that.

Comment: @Panu In regards to something in the calculation causing the slowdown, the code posted is a full working example.

Comment: Ok. Then it is not so likely. :D

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz certainly you're right to suggest using a bit less than the max possible threads. Regardless this issue persists if you drop the thread count down to something like 40.

Comment: Does commenting out the System.out lines change the slow down ratio?

Comment: @Panu I tested it with no print statements and it had no noticeable effect on the runtime

Comment: Does the ArrayList size have any effect. For example new ArrayList(numberOfCounters) instead of 0.

Comment: @Panu Good suggestion about the `SecurityManager`, but as the real work is all looping and counting, I don't see much opportunity for the SM to get involved... the SM only does checks when it's asked to do them for certain things (like accessing files, system properties, etc.). Once those threads have started, they should have no problem with any SM. Still, it's worth checking to see if the JVM has a `SecurityManager` enabled.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I was never able to resolve the problem within tomcat, but for my needs I was able to switch over to glassfish and the the program performs as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to ensure that the total number of threads that Tomcat and your jobs use totals the number of cores on your system?  I would venture to say that you would probably get closer to the 99% execution for those threads.

The other question that I have is if the Tomcat threads have a higher priority than your worker threads.  If that is the case then you should be seeing this difference on a consistent basis.  I do not recall if you can see the thread priority using jconsole or visualvm but maybe increasing the thread priority of the thread pool should provide more cpu cycle but that will affect tomcat ability to handle web requests.